# Window XP should Login with only 1 user created on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2003, group-policy

As I have many user on my server, I have created a domain. I want my system to Login with only 1 specific `username` and `password` and not by others. Which policy should be applied?

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and check this article from Microsoft:

[How to Create a Base Profile for All Users](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168475)

Comment: it dose not work